# Command wbcopytables --table-range not working

Tags: mysql

I am migrating sql server tables in MySQL using wbcopytables command. I want to copy a specific range(id 1-10000) of data from MSSQL to MySQL, so I am using below syntax.

```
wbcopytables --odbc-source="DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=**.**.**.**;PORT=1433;DATABASE=TESTDB;UID=***;PWD=***;TDS_VERSION=7.1" --target="root@127.0.0.1:3306" --force-utf8-for-source --truncate-target  --table-range [TESTDB] [dbo].[DeletedUnits]  TESTDB DeletedUnits Unit_Id Unit_Id 1 10000
```

unfortunately I am getting below error message this syntax.

```
wbcopytables: Invalid option 10000
```

If we remove Unit_Id from select expression from command, the it creates wrong sql for migration like below.

```
ERROR:TESTDB.DeletedUnits:SQLExecDirect(SELECT  FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[DeletedUnits] WHERE Unit_Id >= 1 AND Unit_Id <= 10000): 42000:1156:[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

Comment: Instead, try using MySQL's Workbench for migration.